# Euler's relation (e^(j*pi/4)

Tags: laplace-transform, z-transform

I am doing EE hw right now while going over my notes, I notice that my prof said that e^(j*pi/4) = 1 but how?
Using Euler's, I would get e(j*pi/4) = cos(pi/4) + jsin(pi/4) = 0.7071 + j0.7071 [image]

Comment: Take the magnitude of cos(pi/4) + jsin(pi/4) and you'll get one. x+iy is a vector, it has direction and magnitude. 1 is just the magnitude only, 0.7+0.7j has a magnitude of one and an angle of 45'. Magnitude is sqrt(x^2 + y^2).

Comment: Those vertical lInes mean magnitude

Comment: The edits you have made to your question are wrong for two reasons. 1) you have tried to correct your numbers after I pointed out the problem and 2) the picture you have added (since my answer) is irrelevant. If you are going to edit a question following what is revealed in an answer, make sure you do it in a way that people reading my answer will not be confused into thinking I've missed the point. Common courtesy really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I don't know how you managed to get cos(pi/4) = 0.5 because cos(45) = 0.7071 and sin(45) = 0.7071 too. (These errors were subsequently edited out of the question).

Hence \$\sqrt{0.7071^2 + 0.7071^2}\$ = 1

Answer (score 3):

I would like to point out that complex exponentials are really another way to write complex numbers. So if there is no coefficient of exp(j*omega) then the magnitude is implied to be 1. The coefficient IS the magnitude.

$$ z = \alpha + j\beta = r e^{j\omega} $$
$$ |z| = \sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2} =r$$
$$ \angle z = \arg(z)=\omega=\arctan(\frac{\beta}{\alpha})  $$

Hope this helps